# jQuery Roundabout CSS Position Troubles in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, css, position

I have [Roundabout][1] loaded up into a Wordpress install. The goal is to have it so that I can flip through the posts as the carousel. Functionally speaking everything goes well. I am running into some real trouble with the positioning however.

It appears that Roundabout applies position:absolute to the child elements to make its job of positioning them in the carousel easier. This is all well and good, except I am having the classic problem with absolute positioning pulling the elements out of the flow of the page, and ending up with my main body's height being short, and the elements floating above and outside of it.

I have tried setting several layers up the parent chain to position:relative to no avail. I am honestly out of ideas.

I am working locally, otherwise I'd provide a link for a live example. If it comes down to needing it I'll move the project to a live example.

Thanks everyone

My Roundabout Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#main').roundabout({
                    childSelector:".post",
                    enableDrag: true,
                    autoplay: false,
                    duration: 1000,
                    clickToFocus: true,
                    shape: "square",
                    debug: false
                });
             });
```

My basic HTML structure:

```
    <div id="content">
    <div id="inner-content">
        <div id="main">
            <article class="post">
                Wordpress Content
            </article>
            <article class="post">
                Wordpress Content
            </article>
            <article class="post">
                Wordpress Content
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Appropriate CSS:

```
#content {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}
#content #inner-content {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}
#content #inner-content #main {
  margin: 25px auto;
  width: 85%;
}
#content #inner-content #main .roundabout-holder {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 5em;
  width: 100%;
}
#content #inner-content #main .roundabout-moveable-item {
  height: 4em;
  width: 85%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
#content #inner-content #main .roundabout-in-focus {
  cursor: auto;
}
```

And why not a screen shot for good measure?
[image]

Comment: Just for reference, you can get a live example at http://www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

You have the height of `#content #inner-content #main` set to 5em;  Set it using min-height and making the value the minimum required for the carousel to show in the body frame.  The content should make it grow from there.

Some of the carousels also require some offset padding to accommodate for the forward, backward and frame controls.  Check the documentation carefully for anything like that

```
#content #inner-content #main {
  min-height: 500px; /* or whatever value is required */
}
```

EDIT 3/3/13:

I am adding a link for you to the [standard implementation](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/demos/standard) of Roundabout.  Take a look at the HTML vs what you are doing.  His plugin is list driven `<li>` and that's what you should be using as well.  You'll probably need to adjust your CSS a little bit afterwards but no big deal there.  Just remember if you use someone's plugin that it needs to be setup like the examples they provide for you. If you have issues from that point then it will be much easier to address.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <article class="post">
        Wordpress Content
        </article>
    </li>
    <li>
        <article class="post">
        Wordpress Content
        </article>
    </li>
    <li>
        <article class="post">
        Wordpress Content
        </article>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That sort of works. It causes some other issues I'm currently trying to work my way through. Mostly that when a post extends beyond min-height:x, it still is outside the flow. I realize I could keep raising that number, but a min-height of 1500px just seems so ridiculous for me.

Comment: @TXChetG I added some info for you regarding implementation.

Comment: ul>li is the standard implementation. And I have tried reverting to that method over my option using his built in childSelection method, to no changed results. I'll keep working with the CSS, and possibly go back to a blank slate before trying to work it back into the theme again.

Comment: Yes UI>LI is standard implementation but you do find LI controlling the "tabs" and div's displaying the content like you have above.  You are doing something similar to Adobe's old [Spry Framework](http://blogs.adobe.com/dreamweaver/2012/08/update-on-adobe-spry-framework-availability.html) It's older but still usable in the right situation. If you are having trouble with positioning breaking the flow, take a look at this [article](http://www.impressivewebs.com/absolute-position-css/) it's not the greatest but maybe it will spark an idea or two for you.